# Predeployment of PersistenceUnit failed

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm studying JPA using EclipseLink and I had the following errors and I can't resolve them.
I tried to use hibernate but somehow my PU was found. I soon switched to EclipseLink and had some results, but I have this problem.

Can anybody help me?

**This is the full error stack**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at dao.GenericDAO.<init>(GenericDAO.java:23)
    at dao.GenericDAO.<init>(GenericDAO.java:31)
    at dao.FilmeDAO.<init>(FilmeDAO.java:15)
    at control.GerenciaFilme.adicionar(GerenciaFilme.java:25)
    at view.CadastroFilmes.btnConfirmarActionPerformed(CadastroFilmes.java:283)
    at view.CadastroFilmes.access$000(CadastroFilmes.java:18)
    at view.CadastroFilmes$1.actionPerformed(CadastroFilmes.java:127)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [CineMaxPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/libraries/asm/EclipseLinkClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:191)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at util.JPAConectionFactory.<clinit>(JPAConectionFactory.java:19)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [CineMaxPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

**This is my Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "filme")
public class Filme {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "titulo")
    private String titulo;
    
    @Column(name = "genero")
    private String genero;
    
    @Column(name = "sinopse")
    private String sinopse;
    
    @Column(name = "diretor")
    private String diretor;
    
    @Column(name = "pos_clas_indicativa")
    private int posClasIndicativa;
    
    @Column(name = "ano")
    private int ano;
    
    @Column(name = "duracao")
    private int duracao;
    
    @Column(name = "caminho_imagem")
    private String caminhoImagem;
}
```

**This is my Generic DAO**

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T, I extends Serializable> {

    protected EntityManager entityManager = JPAConectionFactory.createEntityManager();

    private Class<T> persistedClass;

    protected GenericDAO() {
    }

    protected GenericDAO(Class<T> persistedClass) {
        this();
        this.persistedClass = persistedClass;
    }

    public T salvar(T entity) {
        EntityTransaction t = entityManager.getTransaction();
        t.begin();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        t.commit();
        return entity;
    }

    public T atualizar(T entity) {
        EntityTransaction t = entityManager.getTransaction();
        t.begin();
        entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        t.commit();
        return entity;
    }

    public void remover(I id) {
        T entity = encontrar(id);
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        T mergedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.remove(mergedEntity);
        entityManager.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(persistedClass);
        query.from(persistedClass);
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

    public T encontrar(I id) {
        return entityManager.find(persistedClass, id);
    }
}
```

**This is my Conection Factory **

```
public class JPAConectionFactory {
     private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    static {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CineMaxPU");
    }
    
   
    public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager(EntityManager manager) {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

**This is my persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CineMaxPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Filme</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="*****"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tryed to change the persistence.xml but dont worked.

Comment: This is a resource issue - "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/libraries/asm/EclipseLinkClassVisitor" means you don't have the complete EclipseLink jar on the class path. How are you setting up the environment and pulling in EclipseLink?